# Какую нагрузку выдержит сервер?

Tags: php, mysql, сервер

Стало интересно: как посчитать, какую нагрузку выдержит тот или иной сервер?
К примеру, сколько уникальных посетителей сможет выдержать сайт на тарифе https://hosting.reg.ru/hosting/plan/Host-0-0910

Понимаю, что зависит от скриптов, поэтому дам понять:
Каждый запрос - обновление поля в БД, т.е. пользователю обновляется online. При заходе на сайт проверяется значение сессии, если не найден $_SESSION['user'], то перебрасывает на главную страницу.

Если нужно больше инфы - придумаю, поскольку хочу разобраться в этом вопросе, чтобы потом не тыкать пальцем в потолок при разработке бэкэнда сайтов

Comment: Чуть менее чем полностью зависит от конкретной реализации конкретных скриптов

Comment: Зависит от рук программиста. И от того, какими проблемами занят. Если его интересует написание кода, то сайт выдержит большую посещаемость. А если интересуют влажные эротические мечты про офигиллиард хитов на копеечном хостинге, то и один посититель этот сайт завалит.

Comment: Реклама же! Выпишите характеристики тарифа и удалите ссылку.

Comment: `Максимальное количество процессов: 18 (для VIP-тарифов 48);`